# How to re-order elements of an array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays

If I have an array of N elements in C programming, how can I exchange a particular pair of elements?

For instance given the array:

```
double variable[N] = {1, 2, ..., i-1, i, i+1, ..., N-1, N }
```

How could I exchange element i for i+1 in such a way that the new system is given by:

```
double variable[N] = {1, 2, ...,i-1, i+1, i, ..., N-1, N }
```

My attempt is to make a temporary variable:

```
{ double temp = element i ;     element i =element i+1 ;   element i+1 = temp;   }
```

I am dubious as to whether this will advance the variable by one or swap them as required? Unfortunately I am not sure how to implement this in code or even if this is the correct way to do it? In addition, I am unsure of  how to cater for when i=N, so that elements cycle back down through the array.

I am very new to programming and very much appreciate any help offered. Thank you!

Comment: Look up indexing an array and assigning elements to an index in an array

Comment: I would suggest creating a `swap` routine that takes two pointers and then simply using it like this: `swap(&element[i],&element[i+1]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know which elements to exchange, you could do :

```
if (i+1 < N)
{
  double temp = variable[i];
  variable[i] = variable[i+1];
  variable[i+1] = temp;
}
```

I check first if `i+1` is inferior to `N` (remember the index of an array begins by 0) to prevent reading outside the array. Then I do the exchange.

If I understood you, if you have to exchange the last element, you would like that it be done with the first element. In that case, you could change the former `if` to :

```
if (i+1 <= N)
{
  double temp = variable[i];
  variable[i] = variable[(i+1)%N];
  variable[(i+1)%N] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Or just `int toswap = i + 1 < n ? i + 1 : 0;` (or (i + 1) % n)

Comment: Mod happens before addition btw.

Comment: Yes you are right, and yes right again , my mistake. Thanks !

Comment: @Blake_Lead Thank you very much for your time Blake, I really appreciate it! Out of interest how could I make the exchanges swap back down through the loop once they reach N, for instance i=N swaps with j=N-1, to cycle back and forth through the array?

Comment: You are very welcome. To perform what you ask, I think I would use a flag variable that would change value when N is first reached. I would then test the value of this flag variable : if it changed, I would change the order of operation.